# Google Chrome extension: always visible popup

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm develop Google Chrome extension. I'm using browser_action with popup windows. I would like to stay always visible popup when switch tabs?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Persisting Chrome Extension popup between page loads](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10378477/persisting-chrome-extension-popup-between-page-loads)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

popup will auto close when lose focus.

you can use panel instead.

```
chrome.windows.create({ url: 'http://mobile.google.com', width: 320, height: 480, type: 'panel' })
```

It will keep opening across all tabs.

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible, the popup will always close as soon as it loses focus.

If you need an always visible UI, your only option is, probably, injecting it into all pages.